# No Image will load from API only getting undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json, image, api

The main problem I am having is that the image of the game won't load: it just keeps saying undefined when it runs the search.

My second problem is that I want to change it to a search; currently it has a set value, I want to allow the user to input their own title.

I have linked my code below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
              url: "http://api.giantbomb.com/search/",
              type: "get",
              data: {api_key : "key here", query: "star trek", resources : "game", field_list : "name, resource_type, image", format : "jsonp", json_callback : "gamer" },
              dataType: "jsonp"
            });
        });

        function gamer(data) {
              var table = '<table>';
              $.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {
                  table += '<tr><td>' + value.image + '</td><td>' + value.name + '</td><td>' + value.resource_type + '</td></tr>';
              });
              table += '</table>';
              $('#myelement').html(table);
        }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Game Search</h1>
        <input id="game" type="text" /><button id="search">Search</button>
        <div id="myelement"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed two things:

1. `field_list : "name, resource_type, image"` to `field_list : "name,resource_type,image"` fixes 'images' to be null.
2. `image` returns an object: use either `icon_url`,`medium_url`,`screen_url`,`small_url`,`super_url`,`thumb_url` or `tiny_url`

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52FAY/1/) (**do change apiKey to test**)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
              url: "http://api.giantbomb.com/search/",
              type: "get",
              data: {api_key : apiKey, query: "star trek", resources : "game", field_list : "name,resource_type,image", format : "jsonp", json_callback : "gamer" },
              dataType: "jsonp"
            });
        });

        function gamer(data) {
              var table = '<table>';
              $.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {
                  var image = "";
                  if (value.image) {
                      // either icon_url,medium_url,screen_url,small_url,super_ur,thumb_url or tiny_url
                      image = "<img src='"+value.image.tiny_url+"'/>";
                  }
                  table += '<tr><td>' + image + '</td><td>' + value.name + '</td><td>' + value.resource_type + '</td></tr>';
              });
              table += '</table>';
              $('#myelement').html(table);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is undefined because there is more than just "image".

Section of json from the response:

```
"image": {
    "icon_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_avatar/10/103881/1711377-stp1.jpg",
    "medium_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_medium/10/103881/1711377-stp1.jpg",
    "screen_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/screen_medium/10/103881/1711377-stp1.jpg",
    "small_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/10/103881/1711377-stp1.jpg",
    "super_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_large/10/103881/1711377-stp1.jpg",
    "thumb_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_avatar/10/103881/1711377-stp1.jpg",
    "tiny_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_mini/10/103881/1711377-stp1.jpg"
  }
```

You need to call it like value.image.medium_url and put it in an img tag:

```
'<tr><td><img src="' + value.image.medium_url + '"/></td><td>'
```

Comment: tryed adding the img tag getting no image just an error net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND i have linked the documentation as that might help http://www.giantbomb.com/api/documentation

Comment: Try seeing if it prints the url. '<tr><td>' + value.image.medium_url + '</td><td>'

Comment: it didnt it wouldnt show anything it gave the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'medium_url' of undefined GiantBomb(In%20developement%20Search).html:18

Comment: Grabbing the image is the only issue? The name and resource_type print correctly?

Comment: yeah name and resource print its just the image its problay just something simple but i cant figure it out ??????